# Drop columns based on row -index 0

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python and I am trying to drop some columns in a Dataframe based on the variable in row 0. The dataframe looks like this:

```
                                C00         C01         C02         C03  
0      Time(s)/Cell Status    accepted    accepted    accepted    accepted   
1                        0     40.1782   -245.4999    15.96771    53.06083   
2                 0.049961     161.299   -357.6592   -263.0684   -52.77648   
3                 0.099922    244.7165   -338.4682   -298.6496   -34.78166   
4                 0.149883    242.8061   -291.4323   -129.1347   -32.34716
```

The df has many more columns. I am basically trying to remove the columns where row 0 = rejected.
Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like:

```
print(df.loc[:,df.iloc[0]=="accepted"])
```

Comment: I tried the following:

Comment: mask = df.iloc[0].isin(['rejected'])
df = df.loc[:, ~mask]
print (df)

Comment: but it does not seem to work

Comment: @sebabare what do you get?

Comment: mask gives me all FALSE

Comment: @sebabare could run  `from collections import Counter` and  `print(Counter(df.loc[0]))`

Comment: Solved! stupid mistake. realized with counter was ' rejected' instead of 'rejected'. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could extract to columns and then drop them like this:

```
col_to_remove = list(df.iloc[0][df.iloc[0]=="rejected"].index)

df.drop(col_to_remove, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This would return the dataframe after removing the columns:

```
df.drop(df.columns[df.iloc[0] == "rejected"], axis=1)
```

If you want to change the original dataframe, then this:

```
df.drop(df.columns[df.iloc[0] == "rejected"], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Not working. Should I change row type?

Comment: What was the output? It worked for me https://imagebin.ca/v/6KCHWzSgMUSZ

Comment: it did. I just had to use " rejected" instead of "rejected"